# Force Json Properties to be merged into List/Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got a JsonFile with the following structure (im sorry for the german names):

```
"400161": {
"feuerwehrnummer": "someRandomIntagere",
"feuerwehrname": "someCharacters",
"feuerwehrkommandant": {
  "name": "someonesName",
  "dienstgrade": {
    "0": "aa",
    "1": "bb",
    "2": "cc"
  },
  "foto": "fotoPath"
}
"fahrzeuge": {
  "0": {
    "klasse3typ": "L\u00f6schfahrzeuge (B1)",
    "kurzbezeichnung": "LF",
    "name": "PUMPE 2",
    "funkrufname": "PUMPE 2"
  },
  "1": {
    "klasse3typ": "L\u00f6schfahrzeuge (B1)",
    "kurzbezeichnung": "LF",
    "name": "PUMPE 1",
    "funkrufname": "PUMPE 1"
  },
}},
```

i tried parsing it with the JToken.ToObject-Function, where T is this Object:

```
    public int feuerwehrnummer { get; set; }
    public string feuerwehrname { get; set; }
    public string bezirk { get; set; }
    public string abschnitt { get; set; }
    public string gemeinde { get; set; }
    public firefighterPerson feuerwehrkommandant { get; set; }
    public firefighterPerson abschnittskommdandant { get; set; }
    public firefighterPerson bezirkskommandant { get; set; }
    public firefighterPerson landeskommandant { get; set; }
    public int anzahlfeuerwehren_gemeinde { get; set; }
    public int anzahlfeuerwehren_ff_bezirk { get; set; }
    public int anzahlfeuerwehren_btf_bezirk { get; set; }
    public int anzahlfeuerwehren_bf_bezirk { get; set; }
    public List<fireVehicle> fahrzeuge { get; set; }
    public fotoObject foto { get; set; }
```

My Problem occures at the property called "feuerwehrkommandant" at its Descendant "dienstgrade", since i am trying to merge all its descendants into a List as seen here:

```
    class firefighterPerson
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<string> dienstgrade{ get; set; }

    public string foto { get; set; }
}
```

When running the Program i get this Error Message:

> not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   Path '400161.feuerwehrkommandant.dienstgrade.0'.'

(It also occures at the token "fahrzeuge", of course)

I fully understand the Message, but since the api, where i get my data from, doesn't use a JsonArray, but Properties with dynamic names ("1","2",...) i didnt find a way to work aroung this. Is there any way, to tell the deserializer to merge the properties into a list, or do I have to write the deserialization manually?

Comment: i wanted to help you but when i saw how you named things i gave up.

Comment: I guess i will set up a little sample with better names and than ask again

Comment: And please respect the conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dienstgrade { get; set; }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Dictionary<string, fireVehicle> fahrzeuge{get;set;} did also work! That was actually a lot easier than expected. Thank you!